# Using 2 foreach for 2 queries - how to use them together

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I have to make statistics - to compare 2 values. I have made 2 queries.Now it looks like that:

http://prntscr.com/7ckcq2

These progressive bars repeat many times. It should be only one progressive bar for each question.
These statistics show results from a survey. I have to divide average answer of a student for each question from a survey into average answer of all students that have filled the survey for this question. And I'm trying to make 2 foreach loops for these 2 queries. But they repeat many times. How should I use them together?
I'm using CodeIgniter. My view is:

```
 <?php foreach ($average_result as $row) {
        echo "<h4 id='question_name'> Question </h4>";

        $percent_average=(round("$row->answer",2)*20); 
        $point=round("$row->answer",2);
        echo "<br/>";
        foreach($average_student_result as $average) {

        $average_result = round("$average->answer",2);
      $percent=(round("$average->answer",2)*20); 
    ?>
    <div class="progress">
           <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 
            <?php echo round($percent_average,2); ?>%;">

            <?php  echo (round($average_result,2)/round($point,2)); echo "<br/>";
            ?>      
            </div>
        </div>

                    <?php  } } ?>
```

My controller is:

```
 public function average_results_show()
    {


        $data['dynamic_view'] = 'results/average_results';
        $data['average_student_result'] = $this->result_model->average_student_result();
        $data['average_result'] = $this->result_model->result_question();

        $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);  
    }
```

My model is:

```
/* Show average answers of questions of a student */
    public function average_student_result()
    {           
        $this->db->select('survey_questions.question');
        $this->db->distinct('survey_questions.question_id');
        $this->db->select_avg('answer');
        $this->db->from('survey_answers');
        $this->db->join('survey_questions', 'survey_questions.question_id=
        survey_answers.question_id  ');
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata['user_id']);    
        $this->db->where('survey_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->db->group_by('survey_answers.question_id');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
    /* Show average answers of questions */
    public function result_question()
    {           
        $this->db->select('survey_questions.question');
        $this->db->distinct('survey_questions.question_id');
        $this->db->select_avg('answer');
        $this->db->from('survey_answers');
        $this->db->join('survey_questions', 'survey_questions.question_id=
        survey_answers.question_id  ');    
        $this->db->where('survey_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->db->group_by('survey_answers.question_id');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
```

Comment: I think it can be get it from single query itself. Here you wrote two separate functions. Instead you can write single query. If you can provide table structure with sample data ( if possible sqlfiddle ), somebody can help you with good answer.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0118a    Here are my tables - survey_answers and survey_questions.

Comment: I made it to be only one query but in controller I have: $data['average_student_result'] = $this->result_model->result_question($this->session->userdata['user_id']);
        $data['average_result'] = $this->result_model->result_question(); I pass as parameter user_id so in my view I have again 2 foreach, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From top foreach you can get the question id I feel. In $average_student_result array you are getting particular student answered questions array like

```
$average_student_result['question_id'] = 'answer average or answer'; //any value
```

So we can avoid the inside foreach like  `$average_student_result[$row->question_id]`. So you are getting both per student wise as well as overall students wise also. I hope this answer will help.

Comment: I'll try it and I'll write. :)

Comment: I tried to use only one loop:  <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($average_result); $i++) {  echo $average_result['question'] ; echo $average_student_result['answer'];  - This gives me  Undefined index: question, Undefined index: answer.

Comment: I think you are fetching the result array wrongly. Please fetch the $average_student_result arrays index as question_id. If not clear, Please attach the file here please.

Comment: I made it now and it works: echo round(((round($average,2) / $average_result[$i]['answer'])*100),2); echo "%"; Thank you! :)

Comment: Great. You deserved. :)